# VB: Single Data Type Incorrect Addition

Tags: vb.net

The Single data type is not adding as expected. Could someone explain to me why its doing this?

The problem is shown below:

```
Dim h As Single
h += CSng(703.35)  'result: h = 703.35
h += CSng(703.35)  'result: h = 1406.7
h += CSng(703.35)  'result: h = 2110.0498  WTF
```

Comment: floating point math is an approximation.

Comment: if you need precision, use `Decimal` instead.

Comment: "Programming Tips
Precision. When you work with floating-point numbers, keep in mind that they do not always have a precise representation in memory. This could lead to unexpected results from certain operations, such as value comparison and the Mod operator. For more information, see Troubleshooting Data Types (Visual Basic)." ~ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

single means IEEE754. IEEE754 cannot express every single value. It is quite possible that you have values that do not exist in IEEE754, and that the result you get is the nearest approximation.

If you need values that match what us meat-headed humans tend to agree on as the "exact" approximation (note the contradiction in terms), you should be using decimal, not single.

To be clear: both decimal and single are forced to approximate - there is only so much you can do to fit such a range of possible values into finite bytes. But the way they approximate is different. decimal is appropriate for discrete measurements like money; double is appropriate for continuous measurements